# How do I use Win32 APIs (or .NET) to replace a Group with a SidHistory value with a Default Domain value?

Tags: active-directory, migration, azure-active-directory, sid

I have some groups that have members with a legacy domain SID.  The user has been migrated into a central domain and has the legacy domain SID in the SidHistory[] collection.

How can I update the group so that the SidHistory value is no longer present, and the new SID takes its place?

- Could it be as simple as removing and re-adding the user to the group?
- Is there a "cleaner" or more official way?